# save local variables into global vector, why can i got these local variables after leaving local scope?

Tags: c++

```
class MyData
{
    public:
        string str;
        int num;
};

vector<MyData> vec;

void Generate_data()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        ostringstream oss("");
        oss << "str " << i;
        MyData my_data;

        my_data.num = i;
        my_data.str = oss.str();

        vec.push_back(my_data);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Generate_data();

    for (int i = 0, size = vec.size(); i < size; ++i)
    {
        cout << vec[i].num << ": " << vec[i].str << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0: str 0
1: str 1
2: str 2
```

Save local variables into global vector. After leaving local scope, why can i  got these local variables? Shouldn't their memory be released?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You save *a copy* of the local variable in the global container.

Here is an experiment that should make it clear:

```
MyData my_data;
my_data.num = 1;
vec.push_back(my_data);
my_data.num = 2;
cout << vec[0].num << endl;
```

P.S. If you retain a *pointer* to a local variable after the variable has gone out of scope, and then you dereference the pointer (that is, try to retrieve the value of the variable), you may succeed and get the old value, This is **Undefined Behavior,** so anything can happen, including success.

Comment: void Generate_data()
{
    MyData my_data;
    my_data.num = 1;
    my_data.str = "str 1";
    vec.push_back(my_data);

    my_data.num = 2;
}
yes, the output is : 1: str1, 
and another question, i also changed MyData class:
class MyData
{
    public:
        string str;
        int num;
    public:
        MyData(){cout << "MyData constructor" << endl;}
};

but the constructor function is only called once, so how does vector copy my_data? move constructor function?

Comment: @chaohan: **copy** constructor. Add this: `MyData(const MyData &A){str=A.str; num=A.num; cout << "MyData copy constructor" << endl;}`